# JPA Delete with cascade children delete not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I apologize in advance for asking such an often-asked questions, but I haven't been able to find any answers which directly fit my problem. Thus I am writing this question to try and clarify to myself, what is wrong in my code.

I have a web-store application, where users pick items which get added to the cart, and once they checkout, the cart gets deleted, alongside all cart entries.

Here is the Cart class model (parent class):

```
@Entity
public class ShoppingCart {

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shoppingCart", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
     private List<ShoppingCartItem> shoppingCartItems;
}
```

Pretty straight forward as much as I see, it contains a list of CartItems which are held in a separate table.

Here is the ShoppingCartItem class (child)

```
@Entity
public class ShoppingCartItem {

     @ManyToOne
     private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
}
```

Not that I left out most of my class data such as IDs and stuff, they don't add much to the problem.

I have a service method which takes in the ID of the ShoppingCart to  be deleted, and does the following:

- Call ShoppingCartRepository in order to read some data from it before deleting the entry
- Call OrderRepository and save the newly created order, which has no relationship with the cart
- Call `ShoppingCartRepository.deleteById(id)` method on the given cart id, which in theory should delete the ShoppingCart, and then cascade down and delete all it's children ShoppingCartItems

What happens is, the ShoppingCart gets found, Order gets saved, however, the DELETE does not happen. It doesn't crash though, but my cart is still present after calling Checkout.

I then tried a different approach, by manually writing @Query methods, one to delete the children (ShoppingCartItem), then delete the parent (ShoppingCart).

And this works.

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "delete from ShoppingCartItem ITEM where ITEM.shoppingCart.id = :cartId")
void deleteFromCartById(@Param("cartId") long cartId);

@Modifying
@Query(value = "delete from ShoppingCart CART where CART.id = :id")
void deleteViaId(@Param("id") long id);
```

So, suma sumarum, using the `deleteByID(T id)` method from the JPARepository, with attribute `CASCADE.ALL` does not remove neither the parent, nor the child.

However, making custom queries and calling them separately works as expected.

What is the cause of this?

Comment: Isn't Hibernate supposed to handle those things in the background? Also afaik orphan-removal works when I do memory removals and saves?

Comment: No you are responsible to set the relationships correctly when working on the entites

Comment: You should enable SQL logs and check what's Hibernate doing in the background.

Comment: But isn't a delete with attribute Cascade.ALL on the parent object supposed to delete the children and itself, regardless of whether or not I use the orphan-removal attribute? @SimonMartinelli

Comment: Yes, you are right. `CascadeType.ALL` should cascade the `REMOVE` operation also to the collection and elements, so my guess is that something Spring Data JPA related goes wrong here. Not sure what you mean by "calling checkout", but maybe you just forgot to flush?

Comment: @ChristianBeikov Flush didn't work for me, tried it already. I found a way around it by removing children manually, then deleting the parent, but this is only because my model has a single list of children, if it were more complex, this would be horrible to do. I still haven't found a way to deleteById and have it cascade down...